# In xcode it's impossible to add new files into the project

Tags: xcode, macos, cocos2d-x

I found billions of questions and answers about this particular problem but none of solves the issue. I am following some tutorials to learn cocos2d game engine. In the tutorial i follow the tutor uses a windows machine and just puts the sprites he need under the Resources folder. Hovewer on my mac whatever i do theres no way the app will see that the image is there.

I tried dragging and dropping in the finder
using add file dialong from the xcode file menu
dragging from the finder and dropping into the xcode
None of these methods succeded in the end all the time i get the following error [image]
[image]

Comment: If you click on `tt.png`, and open the right sidebar, is your target checked?

Comment: @NobodyNada this is it :) this solves the issue please write this as answer so i can accept and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the File Inspector by pressing Option-Command-1, then make sure your target is checked in the Target Membership section:

[image]

The Target Membership controls which targets the file is included in.  Xcode will skip the file when building your target if your target is not checked, causing it to not be copied to your app.